# Opencart linked to a different database containing a product catalog

Tags: database, api, opencart

I'm rebuilding from scratch a site that has been heavily hard coded and would like to use Opencart for frontend/backend but link to an existing products catalog db. Is this possible? Or by mirroring that database somehow or using an API?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you'd match up your tables, obviously the models in OpenCart are formatted for specific database design. You'd need to build some sort of mapping class that would map the old tables to the OpenCart tables in order to process the data, but that would be a nightmare in my opinion.

There are some import extensions you can buy on the OpenCart marketplace, or there are a few shopping cart conversion websites that will convert the db for a fee. I don't want to advertise them here.  Google is your friend ;)